# SQL not working for a simple SET of one column to another in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, set, sql-update

I am trying to update a field to put relevant data in the `location` column, so it will not be blank. In this case, I would like to copy `airport_address` into the `location` column.

```
airport_address is varchar(500)
location is varchar(100)
```

I would like to copy the 1st 100 char of `airport_address` into `location`

Any idea why this SQL would not be working?

This returns 563 rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_events 
WHERE location LIKE ""
```

This affects 0 rows:

```
UPDATE tbl_events 
SET location = LEFT(airport_address, 100) 
WHERE location LIKE ""
```

This affects 0 rows:

```
UPDATE tbl_events 
SET location = airport_address 
WHERE location LIKE ""
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What's the idea behind using `WHERE location LIKE ""` ?

Comment: Well, one thing I notice is that your `LIKE ""` is using double quotes, which shouldn't normally work in SQL, or at least it's not going to test for a blank value if that's what you're after. Are you pasting in the *EXACT* code that you are really executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_events 
SET location = LEFT(airport_address, 100) 
WHERE 
( location IS NULL )
OR
( LTRIM(RTRIM(location)) = '' )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.  If I use:  SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE ( LTRIM(RTRIM(location)) = '' )  I get 562 rows returned.  If I then use: UPDATE tbl_events SET location = LEFT(airport_address, 100) WHERE ( LTRIM(RTRIM(location)) = '' )   I get 0 rows affected.

Comment: I could still use some help on this if anyone can chime in.  Thanks!